# How to implement operator add "+" in clojure?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, operator-overloading

In Java, it is straightforward to add NDArray y into x.

```java
NDManager manager = NDManager.newBaseManager();
NDArray x = manager.create(3f);
NDArray y = manager.create(2f);
x.add(y);
```

In Clojure

```clj
(def ndm (nd/base-manager))
(def x (nd/create ndm 3.))
(def y (nd/create ndm 2.))

(nd/+ x y) ;; Error 
           ;; This NDArray implementation does not currently support this operation
```

When implementing the same function in Clojure, the compiler never knows array0 and array1 are the variable of NDArray and it never knows to pick up a function `NDArray.add` to add NDArray `y` into `x`. Please advise how to implement operator add "+" in Clojure.

```clj
(ns djl.ndarray
  (:import [ai.djl.ndarray NDArray])
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [+ - / *
                            = <= < >= >
                            identity to-array
                            min max concat
                            get set
                            flatten
                            sort]))
(defn + [array0 array1]
  (.add array0 array1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Have a look at the [scicloj/clj-djl source](https://github.com/scicloj/clj-djl/blob/03a9dff2611c605186af01abd29549eda76a3a94/src/clj_djl/ndarray.clj) for implementation details.

```
(ns stack-overflow-3.djl
    (:require
        [clj-djl.ndarray :as nd]))

(let [manager (nd/new-base-manager)
      v1      (nd/create manager [5])
      v2      (nd/create manager [13])]
    (nd/+ v1 v2))
```

Comment: The library "scicloj/clj-djl source" is incompatible with clojure "1.11.1", this is why I quote this piece of code, not import a whole library.

Comment: It's strange, because I used `[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]`

Comment: Because implementing DJI with Clojure on macOS M1, it seems MXnet doesn't support M1, finally. replace backend framework with PyTorch instead of MXnet. It is working normally.